# What is a proper name for a method that execute SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, methods, naming, conventions

I usually create a class where I put all the methods that execute queries to some kind of database.
Does exists any convention to give correct names to that methods? Maybe I'm doing something wrong but I always have extra-long name like "SelectIdAddressPriorityFromMyTableWhereIp".
What is a good name for that kind of method?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any conventions, but I would recommend naming it based on what it's *for* not on what it *does*. The length of the name wouldn't bother me at all so long as it's descriptive.

Comment: I would be more concerned on the fact that everything is inside a single 'Iwilldoeverything' class. Perhaps you should consider a different pattern.

Comment: You're probably better off making some sort of generic method that'll take a query, a collection of parameters and return the dataset or number of rows affected or whatever, rather than specific methods for every statement you might want.

Comment: @sab669 Yeah, something like insertIntoPostgres(string query, List<npgsqlparameter> values, string options).

Comment: @Steve I have all Postgres insert / select / update in one class. Is it a bad practice? not everything, only the database interactions

Comment: @AndreaCattaneo Usually questions here should have a definitive answer, but in your question the answer will be ever an opinion because there is no accepted standards. (And questions that asks for opinion are usually off-topic here) In any case I would create different files  for every main component (or functionality) of your program. Inside these files I would create static classes named after the functionality (and perhaps prefixed with DB) then you have already removed a great part of you name passing it to the class name. The method inside could be named after the SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE ops

Answer (score 0):

The standard does not give any specific naming convention for the method names. But it is recommended to make the names so that it is familiar and it easily makes the reader(you or some other person) understand what it does. The length of the function is not a matter as long as it is providing the purpose of the method and it is easy to maintain and understand for others.

Comment: Ok, so is the example that I posted "SelectIdAddressPriorityFromMyTableWhereIp" a good name for a method that execute a select id,address,priority from MyTable where ip = "192.168.1.1"?

Comment: @AndreaCattaneo:- As I said, as long as you are finding it understandable  it is good. This will be highly opinion based and controversial as well to say if that is good or bad. *(When things are not specified by standards then it is all about opinion and comfort)*

Comment: "LoadIPAdressData" or something similar should be enough I think, from what database it loads can be looked up from the connection data inside of the method and the where clause can easily be understood because the method will most likely need that as a parameter. This is just an opinion and not anything that is written in stone or something. Giving enough information but not too much information is the way I name methods.

Comment: I will add one thing, if your method is designed to run asynchronously, it should have an `Async` suffix on the method name.